# Get names of keywords for Julia methods

Tags: julia, keyword-argument

I have a function like

```
function f(a = 1; first = 5, second = "asdf")
    return a
end
```

Is there any way to programatically return a vector with the names of the keyword arguments. Something like:

```
kwargs(f)
# returns [:first, :second]
```

I realise that this might be complicated by having multiple methods for a functionname. But I was hoping this would still be possible if the exact method is specified. For instance:

```
kwargs(methods(f).ms[1])
# returns [:first, :second]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `Base.kwarg_decl()`

```
julia> Base.kwarg_decl.(methods(f))
2-element Vector{Vector{Symbol}}:
 []
 [:first, :second]
```

If you need the first parameter `a` as well you could also try:

```
julia> Base.method_argnames.(methods(f))
2-element Vector{Vector{Symbol}}:
 [Symbol("#self#")]
 [Symbol("#self#"), :a]
```